# Hi, everybody. I am solving a 6 kyu problem on code wars and my code doesn't work

Tags: java

everybody. I am solving a 6 kyu problem on code wars and my code doesn't work. Here are the instructions for the task:

You are given a list/array which contains only integers (positive and negative). Your job is to sum only the numbers that are the same and consecutive. The result should be one list.

Extra credit if you solve it in one line. You can assume there is never an empty list/array and there will always be an integer.

Same meaning: 1 == 1

1 != -1

#Examples:

[1,4,4,4,0,4,3,3,1] # should return [1,12,0,4,6,1]

"""So as you can see sum of consecutives 1 is 1
sum of 3 consecutives 4 is 12
sum of 0... and sum of 2
consecutives 3 is 6 ..."""

[1,1,7,7,3] # should return [2,14,3]
[-5,-5,7,7,12,0] # should return [-10,14,12,0]

Here's my code:

```
public static List<Integer> sumConsecutives(List<Integer> s) {
        List<Integer> checkList = s;

        List<Integer> mainList = new ArrayList<>();

        int j = 1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < s.size() - 1){
            mainList.add(i);
            mainList.set(i, s.get(i));

            while(true){
                if (s.get(i) == s.get(j)){
                    mainList.set(i, mainList.get(i) + s.get(j));
                    s.remove(j);
                }
                else break;
            }
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        if (checkList.get(checkList.size() - 1) != checkList.get(checkList.size() - 2)){
            mainList.add(i, checkList.get(j - 1));
        }
        System.out.println(mainList);
        return mainList;
    }
```

Here's my error:

```
Test Results:
 ConsecutivesTest
 test
 Log
Basic Tests
Input: {1,4,4,4,0,4,3,3,1}
Test Failed
 Stack Trace
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
    at Consecutives.sumConsecutives(Consecutives.java:21)
    at ConsecutivesTest.test(ConsecutivesTest.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:39)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:79)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:70)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at io.qualified.junit5.RunTests.main(RunTests.java:25)
```

Everything works in my IDE, but not on the site.

Comment: `s.remove(j);` you sure about this?

Comment: Yes, but how should I?

Comment: I mean, are you sure it's necessary? And even if it didn't cause an error, are you sure it would not break your program anyway?

Comment: What can you recommend in exchange? I'm new to programming

Comment: Just delete that line. You're not doing anything with that list after that. Also, imagine what happens when `j=0`. You remove the first element, then increment `j`. Now `j` points to what was the third element, not the second one, because now the second element is in position 0, not 1.

Comment: One of the best bug-fixing things you can do is logging - output the values of the critical variables so you can see how they change pver time, and you can pinpoint when things start going wrong.  Logging also stays with a program, so write it once and it provides benefits throughout the lifetime of the program.  For example, I would recommend that at the lines where you have `i++` and `j++`, output the whole `mainlist`, `s` and `i` and `j`, so at each iteration you can confirm they are what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the implementation that is underlying the `s` list does not support removal from the `List`, leading to the exception. I would suggest you, as a **quick-and-dirt** solution, to do a copy of the input list like this:

```
List<Integer> sCopy = new ArrayList<>(s);
```

and in this way you will be sure that removal is possible. If you have more time to spend I would revise the approach to avoid that removal operation. It is considered a bad practice to modify input values in a function/method. Clean code approaches have this golden rule: function/methods should avoid having side effects.

For example, look at this:

```
public static List<Integer> sumConsecutive(List<Integer> s){
    int current = s.get(0);
    int count = 1;
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Integer i: s.subList(1, s.size())){ //first one is already counted
        if (current == i){
            count++;
        } else {
            result.add(current * count);
            current = i;
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    result.add(current * count); //this avoid skipping the last one

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks you all. With this code, everything works well.

```
    public static List<Integer> sumConsecutives(List<Integer> s) {
        List<Integer> checkList = new ArrayList<>(s);
        List<Integer> sCopy = new ArrayList<>(s);
        List<Integer> mainList = new ArrayList<>();

        int j = 1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < sCopy.size() - 1){
            mainList.add(i);
            mainList.set(i, sCopy.get(i));

            while(true){
                if (sCopy.get(i) == sCopy.get(j)){
                    mainList.set(i, mainList.get(i) + sCopy.get(j));
                    sCopy.remove(j);
                }
                else break;
            }

            j++;
            i++;

        }
        if (checkList.get(checkList.size() - 1) != checkList.get(checkList.size() - 2)){
            mainList.add(i, checkList.get(checkList.size() - 1));
        }
        System.out.println(mainList);
        return mainList;
    }
```

Comment: Small complexity consideration: this code has a double loop, so it will be O(n^2) probably, while my solution is O(n) for sure.